# WTForm BooleanField and default

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask-wtforms

I have this:

```
force_email = BooleanField('force_email', widget=HiddenInput(), default=False)
```

I was hoping to get the value as false in the HTML template but instead i get

```
input id="force_email" name="force_email" type="hidden" value="y"
```

I had a look at the code of the library and I read some stuff around (overridings, formdata things....a lot of stuff) but I still can't figure out how I can set that field to False, I checked https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/wtforms/fields/core.py#L712 and I tried setting raw_data through the BooleanField but it didn't work as I am probably in the wrong place...

I outta ideas....anyone has ever faced this?Am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: ever tried to do this in your view file `force_email.default = False` ? if doesn't work , try this  `form = formObject(force_email=Flase)`

Comment: I will give it a try, even though I preferred to keep all in the form file(that's why I got rid of the boolean field and used a hidden field directly)

Comment: @odaialghamdi unfortunately it doesn't work at all, I will stick with 

    force_email = HiddenField('force_email', default='false') 

as it is working fine

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in a specific case. Because of my pagination links, I was calling the API with `field=False`. I had to adapt the `false_values` parameter of the Field so that the string 'False' was considered as a False value, cf. [documentation here](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html#basic-fields). In your example :

```
force_email = BooleanField('force_email', widget=HiddenInput(), default=False,
                      false_values=('False', 'false', ''))
```